# SQL Server : return id column using max on different column

Tags: sql-server, group-by

In my table I have the columns `id`, `userId` and `points`. As a result of my query I would like to have the id of the record that contains the highest points, per user.

In my experience (more with MySQL than SQL Server) I would use the following query to get this result:

```
SELECT id, userId, max(points)
FROM table
GROUP BY userId
```

But SQL Server does not allow this, because all columns in the select should also be in the `GROUP BY` or be an aggregate function.

This is a hypothetical situation. My actual situation is a lot more complicated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function in `SQL Server`

```
Select * from
(
select Row_Number() over(partition by userId Order by points desc) Rn,*
From yourtable
) A
Where Rn = 1
```